# Building a Character Generator

Tags: pdf-generation

I'm looking to build a character generator for 5th edition dungeons and dragons, just as a side project. However what i don't know is which language to use. so far Ive narrowed down that i need a language that can successfully export out to a PDF, so that variables submitted to the program get passed and the character sheet can be print. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

many languages should be able to handle this for you. the first question i would ask yourself is what language are you most fluent in?

for me that would be php so i would end up doing this project in a combination of html/js/php.

i have used fpdf for generating pdf that either output to the browser, save to the server, or trigger a download. ( http://www.fpdf.org/ )

fpdf was pretty easy to pick up following the examples.